# Is there a standard abbreviation or symbol for "Transducer"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a standard abbreviation or symbol for "Transducer"? I get tired of constantly having to write out the word in full, and also making it a box in diagrams. In my case it's even worse - the full term is "ultrasonic transmitter/receiver transducer". Yes, I can shorten it a bit with Tx/Rx...

Comment: At the beginning of you documents, place an "acronyms and definitions" paragraph, define UTRT as "ultrasonic transmitter/receiver transducer" there, and then use UTRT all throughout the doc. Done !

Comment: Usually each type of transducer has its own symbol; some complex transducers (due to the limited nature of their use) often have no standard symbol.

Comment: I would think that process engineers would want the transducer named for the physical input and output rather than the technology used for the instrument - L/I level to current for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this site](http://www.electronic-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/sensors-transducers-symbols.htm), which seems to provide a generic "transducer" symbol

[image]

Comment: It's always okay to accept your own answer. Waiting a few days is reasonable, a few years is laudable.

Answer (score 2):

There are standards for symbols used on piping and instrumentation and process control diagrams. It is usually a circle containing a letter code for the type of transducer. I have also seen a square with a diagonal line through it. Search P&I Diagram and Process Control Diagram. The ID number often needs to be in the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The following webpage includes symbols for many transducers where one side is electrical: https://electronicsclub.info/circuitsymbols.htm ;
   I was looking for a comprehensive list of symbols which also included transducers where neither side was electrical.